# How to make the <div> elements table-like?

Tags: html, css

I have 2 div classes. The first is class is `.first-div` and the second class is `.second-div`. Now it's looks like this:

[image: Divs]

How can I float the second div's next to the first div's in css?

My current css code:

```
.first-div {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 150px;
border: 1px solid black;
}

.second-div {
float: left;
width: 150px;
}
```

Comment: you would need to float **both** of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.first-div {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 150px;
border: 1px solid black;
float: left;
}

.second-div {
float: left;
width: 150px;
}
```

Add float left to first one as well;